# Unable to send Mail using smtp due to AuthenticationException

Tags: android, email, authentication, smtp-auth

I am using following class to send Mail but in response i am getting some exceptions, which i have pasted here. Username and password are correct, what could be the possible reason of errors?

Code:

```
package com.mailsend;

import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String _user;
    private String _pass;
    private int emailType;

    private String[] _to;
    private String _from;

    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;

    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;

    public Mail() {
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
        _port = "465"; // default smtp port
        _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

        _user = ""; // username
        _pass = ""; // password
        _from = ""; // email sent from
        _subject = ""; // email subject
        _body = ""; // email body

        _debuggable = true; // debug mode on or off - default off
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
                .getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }

    public Mail(final String user, final String pass, int emailType) {
        this();

        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
        this.emailType = emailType;
    }

    public boolean send() {
        try {
            Properties props = _setProperties();

            if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
                    && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
                    && !_body.equals("")) {
                //props.put("mail.smtp.user", _from);
                Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
                // Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Mail(_user,
                // _pass));
                MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

                InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
                    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
                }
                msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

                msg.setSubject(_subject);
                msg.setSentDate(new Date());

                if (emailType == 1) {
                    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
                    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                    msg.setContent(_multipart);
                } else if (emailType == 2) {
                    msg.setText(_body, "utf-8", "html");
                }

                // send email
                Transport.send(msg);
                Log.d("usm_mail", "sendind msg " + _body);

                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)  { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return false;
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

        if (_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if (_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return props;
    }

    // the getters and setters
    public String getBody() {
        return _body;
    }

    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
    }

    public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._to = toArr;
    }

    public void setFrom(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._from = string;
    }

    public void setSubject(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._subject = string;
    }

    // more of the getters and setters �..
}
```

Exception:

```
System.out: DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.1
I/System.out: DEBUG: not loading file: /system/lib/javamail.providers
I/System.out: DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/lib/javamail.providers: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
I/System.out: DEBUG: !anyLoaded
I/System.out: DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.providers
I/System.out: DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
I/System.out: DEBUG: failed to load any providers, using defaults
I/System.out: DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
I/System.out: DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]}
I/System.out: DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]}
I/System.out: DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
I/System.out: DEBUG: !anyLoaded
I/System.out: DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
I/System.out: DEBUG: not loading file: /system/lib/javamail.address.map
I/System.out: DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/lib/javamail.address.map: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
I/System.out: DEBUG: failed to load address map, using defaults
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
I/System.out: DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
I/System.out: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP s136sm11447877pgc.38 - gsmtp
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465
I/System.out: EHLO localhost
I/System.out: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [202.166.173.132]
I/System.out: 250-SIZE 35882577
I/System.out: 250-8BITMIME
I/System.out: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
I/System.out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
I/System.out: 250-PIPELINING
I/System.out: 250-CHUNKING
I/System.out: 250 SMTPUTF8
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
I/System.out: DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
I/System.out: AUTH LOGIN
I/System.out: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
I/System.out: dmVsb2Zvb2RyMUBnbWFpbC5jb20=
I/System.out: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
I/System.out: eTF5MnkzeTQ=
I/System.out: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsq
I/System.out: 534-5.7.14 FA9KEamJQo2BxbjXpwkW-oz0-yU2OUblChDH9fx85CwWNKILKOzTk4TDoV5_QoS16XYYhA
I/System.out: 534-5.7.14 EPVtOfrH8jQV1PCdWUEm5UzNG6dlEwDt61I6NX0GBl7Mox6bcf_CZbUJsb9nJBlOV8xYmn
I/System.out: 534-5.7.14 z6cleMLGilD11Ip28kdjuAd27XwUqYPS4TTjna3CwJHZD-IBL10o1TTU3JmDo_DvTEA395
I/System.out: 534-5.7.14 qcLXXeO1h58qBU8OkP1J9KQM5GUs8> Please log in via your web browser and
I/System.out: 534-5.7.14 then try again.
I/System.out: 534-5.7.14  Learn more at
I/System.out: 534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 s136sm11447877pgc.38 - gsmtp
W/System.err: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
W/System.err:     at com.mailsend.Mail.send(Mail.java:113)
W/System.err:     at com.restaurant.app.DashboardActivity$Send_Mail_Task.doInBackground(DashboardActivity.java:183)
W/System.err:     at com.restaurant.app.DashboardActivity$Send_Mail_Task.doInBackground(DashboardActivity.java:131)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your google account settings does not allow connecting to it by external applications other than gmail or google. Your credentials are ok, but your application seems less secure seen by gmail. See the link https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Are you sending mails in a loop? For example sending 100 mails and each send operations performs login? Commertical accounts of gmail does not permit login in  series. You have to login once and use the same session for further send operations. Can it be case? For example multiple apps. perform send and also perform login and it is blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling Transport.send

you may try

```
transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, username, pass);
```

and check the result of connect call. If succeeds, continue with

```
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients())
```

on the other hand, you may add this to your props

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true")
```